authDomain not updating on Firebase project config
I updated authDomain on firebaseConfig in config.js to match the production URL so it didn't cause problems when using redirection sign in.
But it's still using the old URL for redirection, and on the Firebase project configuration, the SDK config shows the old URL too.
How can I modify it?

I modified the config.js file to use a new authDomain, pushed to repository, Firebase build got updated.

Expected app to use the new authDomain when using redirection sign in.

App still uses old URL.


